# Read CSS attributes from CSS-Class

Tags: css, javafx

I have to workarround a JavaFX8-Bug. Is it possible to read out all css attributes from a CSS-Class.

For Example:

`.test { 
    -fx-background-color: red;
}`

What I want is to get this as a String `-fx-background-color: red;`

Comment: What is this for a bug? Is it really neccessary to read the styles of a CSS class to workaround it?

Comment: It's some kind of update problem: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19089. I add a class for an element for a temporary status. But sometimes the class change does not directly change class the view.